# Scanner useDelimiter String parameter?

Tags: java

I need to set the delimiters of specific `Scanner` object to be: a new line, any number of consecutive spaces, a comma character, and a dollar sign character.

I am using this code:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner("just\ndo      it$bro,tm");
s.useDelimiter("\\n|,|\\s*\\s|\\$");
System.out.println(s.next());
System.out.println(s.next());
System.out.println(s.next());
System.out.println(s.next());
System.out.println(s.next());
```

Its output is:

```
just newline
do newline
it newline
bro newline
tm newline
```

It marks the desired characters as delimiters as intended, but when two consecutive delimiters are encountered, `System.out.println(s.next());` outputs a new line at that instant.

for example if `Scanner s = new Scanner("just\ndo      it$bro,tm");` is changed to `Scanner s = new Scanner("just\ndo   ,   it$bro,tm");` the output becomes:

```
just newline
do newline
newline
newline
it newline
```

`System.out.println(s.next());` outputs a new line when it finds spaces followed by a comma, and another new line when it finds a comma followed by spaces. How can I solve this to make it treat the consecutive delimiters as one delimiter?

I mean to produce output like the first output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `+` at the end of your regular expression to indicate that you could have several consecutive separators, like this:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner("just\ndo   ,   it$bro,tm");
s.useDelimiter("(,|\\s|\\$)+");
System.out.println(s.next());
System.out.println(s.next());
System.out.println(s.next());
System.out.println(s.next());
System.out.println(s.next());
```

**Output:**

```
just
do
it
bro
tm
```

**NB:** No need to use `\\n` and `\\$` in your regular expression, use only `\\$` as it is more generic